# facebook sdk: unable to recover my data

Tags: android, facebook

I'm following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

but something gone wrong when i launch my app. After some launch, the AlertDialog ask me that my app need to access to my public profile, doesn't appear, and onCompleted method never get fired

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String TAG = "FACEBOOK";
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "openactivesession ,call with state "
                            + state.toString());

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Session is opened");
                // make request to the /me GRAPH API that retrieve info
                // about ME
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user
                    // object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "inside onCompleted");
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "user not null");
                            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                            tv.setText("Hello "+ user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getName());
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}

/*
 * onAcitvityResult is called when we start an activity to get a result
 * (with startActivityForResult() ). After started activity ends, return his
 * result as Intent (third args)
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstandroidapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
</application>
```

i don't know what could be the problem. I've try to generate a new hash too, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code **.executeAsync();** after **Reqest.newMeRequest**

```
 Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // Your code here

                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: The docs you linked to uses Request.executeMeRequestAsync, which creates the request AND calls executeAsync, whereas you only had Request.newMeRequest.

Comment: Request.executeMeRequestAsync has been deprecated. It is a method of Facebook SDK 3.0.1